# Want to reuse the functions return value, Function is in namespace Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces, javascript-namespaces

I have a very basic and simple question.
I am using the pattern as below for declaring `namespace`:

```
$.Test= {
    CheckIfListExist: function () {
        //Something is happening here
    },
    TestFunction:function(){
        var tar=get some value;
        return tar;
    },
    Test1:function(){
        //do something
    }
};
```

Now question is in this the function `TestFunction` has a return value
so how can i use it inside a `DOM` or anywhere else for that matter?

I tried the below that gives par `undefined` which is understandable but i am not able to figure out how to do this

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var par = SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', $.Test.TestFunction);
});
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: If you want the return value the function must be called like: `$.Test.TestFunction()`.

Comment: We need to see more of the logic of your `$.Test.TestFunction` to be able to help you. Also, I would strongly suggest you don't pollute jQuery's `$` namespace. Create your own if required.

Comment: I tried to get the return value by using var par=$.Test.TestFunction(); this does not give me anything as i am using this query in sharepoint and in this the 2 main JS files are not loaded unless I do what I did in the doc ready of this question

Comment: Can you give me an Example Rory of creating my own namespace if possible with above pattern?

Comment: A better explanation. if you want the return value the function must be called like: `var par = SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', $.Test.TestFunction());` The function needs to be called like `functionName()` to return his result.

Comment: That also doesn't work. With this syntax its not executing the function at all gives context undefined error.